# How can I share snapshots between Jest tests?

Tags: jestjs, tdd, snapshot

Using TDD I'd like to write some new tests that create data in slightly different ways, and verify that that test data gets sanitized down to the same data as a previous test.

So after writing Test 1 and generating a snapshot, Test 2/3/4 should generate the *same* snapshot as Test 1.

How can I make that happen?  Jest appears to prepend the test name to custom snapshot names so I can't use `.match(test1name)`.

(Using all-new identical snapshots for each test bloats the snapshots file and seems far from ideal.)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```js
const r1 = fn1()

expect(r1).toMatchSnapshot()

const r2 = fn1()

expect(r2).toEqual(r1)
```

Comment: hmm. except that if r1 and r2 require a pristine state (and there may be many tests that follow on to this) it is necessary to simultaneously have a full state instance for each variant, and further to collate requests.  I wish jest would just support this natively, i thought the whole point of using a library like this is not having to reinvent the wheel yourself.